# How can I integrate Bugzilla issues with issue tracking in TortoiseHg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bugzilla, issue-tracking

How should I set the "Issue Tracking" parameters "Issue Regex" and "Issue Link" to enable linking to "Bug [number]" from TortoiseHg?

The Issue Link should be in a format like this:

```
http://www.company.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=[number]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

Issue Regex: `Bug (\d+)`

Issue Link: `http://www.company.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id={1}`

This will make the text `Bug 123` be underlined in the commit messages and clicking on it will go to `http://www.company.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=123`

Comment: Works like a treat! Setting Issue Regex to [Bb]ug (\d+) allows for lowercase (bug) as well.